# PyMC tests on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, pymc

I installed PyMC on Ubuntu 12.10.

Python 2.7.3 32-Bit.

When I try to run:

```
import pymc
pymc.test()
```

I get:

```
Running unit tests for pymc.tests 
NumPy version 1.7.1 
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy 
Python version 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) [GCC 4.7.2] 
nose version 1.1.2
----------------------------------------------- Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

I have up to date HDF5 and PyTables intalled as well.

Is there a reason why the tests are not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. With older versions of `nose`, the tests are unable to run when they are inside an .egg archive. You can try installing them unzipped (-Z) or using a newer nose.